# Are 'Mechs included in A Time of War's core book?

Tags: battletech

I'm considering buying [The latest core book for BattleTech](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/64580/BattleTech-A-Time-of-War-the-BattleTech-RPG) RPG, and from the 7 page preview on DriveThruRPG I can't tell whether there are any mechs given playable stats in the book.

Given that from prior dabbling in the BattleTech universe you have to buy additional books to get additional 'Mech designs, I'm a little concerned that this is more of the same and I'll be splashing out for more books in little to no time.

Are there any 'Mechs included in the core book, and if so what are they?

Comment: Define what you mean by 'detailed' and 'included'. Do you mean, full boardgame design details, mentions of the designs, in-universe stats, costs, or just on lists for generating a mech/unit?

Comment: I wasn't aware that the board game was somehow intrinsically required to play this RPG. I meant 'included' as in there is an entry in the core book for a given mech, and 'detailed' as in having stats to work in the RPG; otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: Well, as others have pointed out, there is a lot more going on in the Battletech universe that Mech combat. Once I get back home, I'll do some better research on the RPG rulebook. It was unclear (at least to me) what you were asking before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the rules for doing vehicle combat are included in the core book, **actual Vehicle stats are not included**.  This is because (like in older editions) the information for 'Mechs is not as simple as a two line stat block.  To properly be displayed, it takes at least half of a page.  This is why they defer to Total Warfare for the larger scale combat and to the books of record sheets, which thankfully the system really hasn't changed much over the years.

There is software to get the 'Mech sheets by demand so that you can print whatever you need whenever you need them, but they like to sell the books (which I believe allow you to copy as much as you want [legally] once you own the record book).

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise answer in bold, made it clear to me that there aren't any mechs included, although the numerous links in the answer by @YogoZuno were helpful.

Comment: I +1'd Yogo's answer for sure.  There were useful snippets in there.

Answer (score 4):

The tabletop or boardgame of Battletech has long been the primary focus of the Battletech designers. In all previous incarnations of the Battletech RPG (with various names - A Time of War is just the latest), the Core RPG rulebook referred players to the tabletop game for mech stats, or to play games focused on mech combat. As far as I can tell, this edition is no different. Contrast this with a game like Heavy Gear that features a similar setup, but has vehicle/mech stats as an intrinsic part of the RPG game system.

All mech designs for Battletech these days are to be found in the [TROs](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/browse.php?keywords=technical%20readout&cPath=4541&x=0&y=0&author=&artist=&pfrom=&pto=) (Technical Read Outs). The occasional special design might be found in other books. However, [Total Warfare](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/24642/BattleTech-Total-Warfare?cPath=4541&it=1), the current core boardgame rulebook, does not have rules for mech construction, meaning there is not even the usual example design in the main rulebook, unlike previous editions. Instead, the construction/design rules for all types of Battletech vehicles are all encapsulated in the the [Tech Manual](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/24750/BattleTech-TechManual?cPath=4541&it=1).

If it helps, there is an independant [Battletech Wiki](http://www.sarna.net/wiki/Main_Page) with descriptive details of almost all variants of mechs (but no actual stats). There is also an official Catalyst-maintained [site](http://www.masterunitlist.info/) that lists all known Battletech units, and their Battle Values, but basically no other design information.

Comment: Wait. There's a *Battletech* role-playing game in which characters aren't mech pilots and there are no stats for mechs? That's... *mean.* Isn't that like sitting down to play *Vampire: The Masquerade* and having the Storyteller say, "Okay, you're all mundanes, and there're are no vampires in this campaign."

Comment: Keep in mind  that Battletech has lots of other stuff, like some ridiculously convoluted politics. Plus, ATOW characters are capable of being pilots (they can function as normal battlefield pilots), it's just not the focus of the game.

Comment: It's not the MANDATORY focus of the game, but it can be. You can have games with nothing but mechwarriors, and games with no mechwarriors. Much like any other game or setting, it's up to GM and players to work out their frames of reference for the game. I've also heard of games where everyone has one mechwarrior, and one non-mechwarrior, all from the same mercenary unit. This allows everyone to be involved in whatever scene the GM is running.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer my question; from the language used, it seems like the book I'm concerned with in my question isn't actually being referenced except for conjecture, with heavy reference to a board game. Does the core RPG rulebook contain mechs with stats, so as to use them in the system?

Comment: Awesome - now that you've come back and clarified exactly what you meant, I'll modify the answer to suit.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: That's a little like demanding that all Star Wars games are about Jedi fighter pilots.  Sure, they *can* be, and it's fun if they are, but it's just one tiny fraction of the RP fun to be had in the universe.  A SW game that *assumed* you were all Jedi fighter pilots would be a really bad game design.

Comment: You can find mech stats available in programs like Heavy Metal Pro, Solaris Skunk Werks, and MegaMek if needed (the last two I know are free, while the former is a pay-to-get mech-sheet creator/printout source - I own copies of all three). You can use these as a free source (especially Solaris Skunk Werks or SSW for short) to help find, study, or build mechs.

Comment: @Tynam I don't think its unreasonable to demand some small amount of information on one or two 'Mechs in the core book in order to let the mechwarrior character actually be able to pilot a mech. Its like saying "Cool, you want to be a Jedi fighter pilot, but we're not going to let you know how any force powers work, or stats for any single fighter you can pilot, out of the box, and you need another book immediately."

Comment: @Tynam Am I a Philistine for wanting at least *some* warring in the stars in something called *Star Wars*? The Bat-man in [*Gotham*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotham_(TV_series))? Magic in [*Sorcerer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorcerer_(film))? Yeah. Never mind.

Comment: In much the same way that Edge of the Empire has no stats for Star Destroyers, and yet they could still feature in the game as background, there are no Mech stats in A Time of War, and yet they could still feature in the narrative.

Comment: Funny in that in an earlier comment Hey I Can Chan said it was like Masquerade. NWoD did something similar: a universal core with (technically) expansions for Vampires and Wolfies. Thus you'd have cores without essential rules.

Answer (score 1):

Time of War is the RPG formally known as Mechwarrior. This for role playing mechpiolets or other soldier types. If you want the mech stats then the Battletech books (tech spechs, Battletech tabletop game) are still needed.

Comment: Hi Mark, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Thanks for your answer. Check out the [tour] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep, you're welcome to join us in [chat].

Answer (score 1):

The Battletech Tactical Companion app by CGL has all mech sheets.
The tabletop game doesn't come with many mech sheets.

https://bg.battletech.com/downloads/ has free pdfs, some of which include mech sheets.

Other books which have mech sheets include "Spotlight on:" series. I have the "Spotlight on The Crimson Hawks" and it includes the mech sheets for all their mechs, including the famous Phoenix Hawk LAM.
"Technical Readouts" are focused on mech stats, while "Record Sheets" solely have the Mech sheets.

There is a free quick start pdf for A Time of War in the link I posted, and the full book also gives information on how the RPG can be adapted so that it can be completely run with the Tabletop rules